# Ассинхронная загрузка игры

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Как можно сделать асинхроную загрузку игры?

Вариант первый, сделать сцену и из неё уже загружать, но вот проблема, загрузка даже такой сцены идет долго, а потом она на мик только появляеться, есть много игр где нет такого, где виден прогресс бар и что-то типо такого, я понял что проблема в том что папка ресурсов слишком заполненая и из-за этого так долго (3-4 секунды) загружаеться игра, можно ли как-то сделать загрузку папки ресурсов из второй сцены либо сделать загрузочный экран с прогресс баром?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сцену можно загружать асинхронно. И процесс загрузки можно выводить на прогресс бар. Используйте SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync В [примере](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html) из официальной документации почти 1 в 1 ваш случай. Делаете очень легкую сцену (например, одна картинка на весь экран) с прогресс баром. И заказываете подгрузку тяжелой сцены, выводя прогресс подгрузки на прогресс бар.

Comment: проблема никак не в сцене, мне нужно именно самую первую сцену загрузить асинхроно, ведь она грузить 3-4 секунды, просто в папке с ресурсами много файлов, даже если сделать первую сцену из одного скрина будет так ж история

Comment: Папка с именем resources - зло. Это название особенное в юнити. Используйте её очень осторожно! Дело в том, что всё добро из этой папки грузится в память при запуске игры и никогда не выгружаются оттуда. Даже если, скажем, у вас уровень 1 картинка и кнопки (типа главного меню), всё равно сцена будет грузится долго, пока не загрузится всё, что есть в папках с таким названием. Вот что говорит официальная документация: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/resources-folder Попробуйте переименовать папки, будет вам счастье :)

Comment: @Akimov я так понял просто держать все ресурсы в кеше скрипта второй сцены?

Comment: Как вариант - да. Привязать все нужные ресурсы к сцене. Сцен одновременно в юнити может быть открыто несколько. Скажем, есть специальная, пустая сцена - для барахла. И она не выгружается пока идут игровые уровни. К ней дополнительно подгружатся сцены с содержимым уровней, и выгружаются. А она в памяти висит. Вот её и будете загружать с прогресс баром.

Comment: Ищите  LoadSceneMode.Additive   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html

Comment: @Akimov еще раз обращусь, ведь я так и сделал, в папке ресурсов один файл на 5 кБ, но всеравно то что и я говорил выше повторяеться, как я сделал, я сделал один класс ResourcesHelper, куда поместил в кеш все префабы из папки ResourcesH, и достаю с помощью екземпляра (т.е. кеша) этого класа RH.Объект, но почему-то дальше все происходит так же.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87186/discussion-between-kitsorik-and-aleksandr-akimov).